# show that a language is context-free by giving a pushdown automaton that accepts the language

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

Given the language $K$ : the words x$y where x and y have odd lengths on {a, b} and the median letter of x is equal to the median letter of y.

Example:

abb$b and

aaaaa$bab are in K

aba$abaab isn't in K

So i am kinda lost here, i am trying to figure out how to do this problem. I struggle to understand how will it recognize that the numbers are odd and how can it know that the median of both words are the same letter.

Could anyone help please, thanks a lot.

I started this drawing but i am so unsure on what to put on state 2 and 3 to make it work.
( I used : http://madebyevan.com/fsm/ if u wanna draw).

[image]

**EDIT**
I wrote a new solution this seem ok, if someone could confirm it would be nice.

[image]

Comment: By "odd numbers" do you mean "odd length"?

Comment: @roundsquare yes sorry, i'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CFG would be much easier , then it can be converted to a PDA :

The $ was replaced by #

S --> A # A | B # B

A --> ΣAΣ | a

B --> ΣBΣ | b

Σ --> a | b

Hopefully you can see that A generates all strings of odd length with a in middle and B generates all strings of odd length with b in middle ,

And so S generates the strings correctly

Comment: Thanks for the CFG approach but is it because my PDA is not right ?  Or is my PDA also good ? Thanks

Comment: Your PDA does a great job in guessing which symbol is in the middle of x and in the middle of y but it has no means of comparing middle symbols of x and y , instead  a better PDA is simply a union of 2 much simpler PDAs , one that always has a as middle symbol in x and y , and one that always has b as middle symbol in x and y ,  so the answer will be the union of 2 PDAs each being the same one you provided with only a minute change that is in the middle we only have a transition for a or only for b only  , that is in each of the 2 PDAs keep only one of the transitions a,ε,ε or b,ε,ε

Comment: so one side would be with a,e,e and the other one b,e,e right ? but if i don't have both on this place, it means that i will only have the words that ALWAYS has an a as a median in the first word, when with the language a b  as the median in the first word should also be possible no ? Thanks

Comment: No ,see the PDA you provided , now make 2 of these , one would be Pa with only a,ε,ε (removing the b,ε,ε) , this PDA recognises strings in correct format but with a being the middle symbol of x and y , the other PDA , Pb has only b,ε,ε (removing the a,ε,ε) and recognises all string in correct format with b being middle symbol of x and y , now the PDA P to recognise the whole language is P  = Pa U Pb , hopefully this makes more sense now

Comment: Here is a quick sketch for the PDA the dotted rectangle is the only part changed from your PDA 
 https://photos.app.goo.gl/5D6QjeZSiANQYExu8

Comment: Ahhhh i understand now what you were saying thanks for taking time to draw it, now i understand why mine failed to verify. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a little while since I've done this stuff, so sorry if my description isn't great. But here is an approach you can flesh out.

- Start in $x_L$. This state scans the input and pushes onto the stack until it randomly decides to switch to $x_?$ state.
- In $x_?$ state it looks to see if the current character is $a$ or $b$ and moves to $x_a$ or $x_b$ depending on which one it sees.
- In either $x_a$ or $x_b$ it starts popping off the stack. If it gets to $\#$ before the stack is empty or it empties the stack before it gets to $\#$ it fails. Otherwise, if it gets to $\#$ exactly when the stack is empty, it moves to $y^a_L$ or $y^b_L$ depending on if it is in $x_a$ or $x_b$.

At this point, if it hasn't failed, it knows that $x$ is of odd length and if the middle character is $a$ or $b$. Then, you can do something similar for $y$ and only succeed if both middle characters are the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand the answer since i am more visual, but i tried a new answer in the original post if you could confirm it works, it would be nice :)